# Lookup .txt files

Tags: c, file

Firstly i must say that my english is not very strong, so please forgive me.

I have got a question about my project.

how do you search for text files on a local drive, i.e files with the .txt extension using the C programming language.

Comment: Edited text and voting to reopen. @mahmoud if you don't like the edit, feel free to roll back. You should add whether you mean to search *recursively* (in sub-directories) or only in `C:\` proper